# Extract data from Table (digits) pdf using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, ocr, python-tesseract

This is my first post here so I hope that I am doing everything right!
I am trying to extract digits from a pdf table (scanned pdf)
sample pdf and images can be found here
`https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/10HtIL3lESSTWtuzbcW6VAcAV4wP4XIij?usp=sharing`
I tried two approaches
first trying to detect everything using Pytesseract

1. The script couldn't detect digits at the beginning but after a little search it detected something like that

[Just random numbers with no sequence to extract](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1ynY.png)

2. I realized that it may need OpenCV first to detect the cells and then do OCR

so I tried something like that
[extract uniform tables from images](https://github.com/Iamsunilsharma/Stackoverflow-Answers/blob/master/How%20data%20is%20extracted%20from%20a%20data%20table%20in%20the%20form%20of%20an%20image%20using%20OCRs.ipynb)

right now I am stuck and don't know how to solve this, if anyone can give me a clue or something it would be great.

Main problem :

- how to extract data from such a table

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Try using `easyOCR`

Comment: I  tried easyOCR but fail again.